# Is the buoyant force on an object a kind of normal force?

Tags: free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy

So, simple question, are the bouyant force applied to an object by a fluid and normal force (Is it even there?) related?

If no where is the normal force and why does bouyancy even happen?

Answer (score 6):

**Normal force** is a term used specifically for the perpendicular reaction force from Newton's 3rd law that a surface produces when it feels a load.

(FYI, similarly, friction is the term used for the equivalent parallel reaction force.)

You could split you surface into smaller pieces and still consider the perpendicular reaction force as a normal force. But if you split into so small pieces, that you are basically just dealing with a particle which, then there is no meaning in the term *perpendicular* anymore and thus the reaction force would *no longer* be called a normal force.

Now, within fluids, buoyancy is the collective force of all fluid particles pushing on the object. As it is a result of individual particles without solid structure, we again have no sense of perpendicularity to those particles. So no, I would argue that buoyancy cannot be considered a normal force.

Note, that when the submerged object feels the collective buoyancy force, then via Newton's 3rd law it responds with a reaction force, which *we could call* a normal force. This would then be opposite in direction to buoyancy.

Comment: It makes sense to split the surface area elements and still have perpendicularity defined there.

Answer (score 3):

The buoyancy force is equal to the magnitude of the weight of fluid displaced and will act in direction opposite to the gravitation force at the centre of buoyancy (centre of gravity of the displaced fluid).

Answer (score 2):

The bouyant force comes from the hydrostatic pressure of any fluid.Because bigger pressure is exerted on the bottom of the object submerged to fluid than the top , any object inside a fluid feels a force which makes the object float at the surface of the fluid.

Answer (score 2):

No it shouldn't be classified as a normal force since you can still have buoyancy in air (since air is a fluid) but still the buoyancy of air and normal of ground are two different things. Buoyancy is defined for fluids and Normal is defined for a contact force from solid